# eBay Shipping Quote from External API

Tags: ebay-api

Is it possible to retrieve shipping quotes on the fly through an external API when a user purchases something through my eBay store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eBay (and previously PayPal) does not expose the shipping quotes API for various reasons (including technical, business, and pricing reasons) so the short answer is "no, there is no way". In fact it gets the quotes from an external (independent) source.

You can try integrating with [Pitney Bowes](http://www.pitneybowes.com/us) or a similar provider to get the shipping quotes but that solution is for large players.

**UPDATE**: Since your company is the one hosting the quote service...

When a user purchaes an item on ebay a "purchase notification" is sent out to a merchant. There are a few different versions of it which you can read about on eBay's dev site. One of them is [ItemSold Notification](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Notifications/Notif-ItemSold.html) that you can use.

**UPDATE 2**:

If I understand you correctly you are trying to inject some business logic into eBay's purchasing UI? I'm afraid you are out of luck here. You have limited (pretty much none) influence on the eBay's web flow.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question. I want to get a non-eBay shipping quote when a user is checking out through my site on eBay. This might not totally make sense, but I don't really use eBay a whole lot.

Comment: The answer is still pretty much the same - there are providers out there that can give you shipping quotes as an API service. One of them is Pitney Bowes (mentioned in the answer above) but I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: My company hosts a quote service - I'm trying to allow eBay users to use our quotes.

Comment: Oh, that changes my answer then.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clearly stating. Mind modifying your answer?

Comment: Again, I feel this is a failure of explanation on my part. I want the user to see our quotes when they are purchasing my products on eBay. Is this a thing?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are trying to inject some business logic into eBay's purchasing UI? I'm afraid you are out of luck here. You have limited (pretty much none) influence on the eBay's web flow.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, YePhick. I'm not very familiar with eBay. (On a personal level, I avoid it at all costs) Will you please update your answer again and I will mark it as the correct answer?